# Random circles JAVA

Tags: java, user-interface, geometry

I am trying to create a GUI that will take in the number of circles to draw, and draw them in drawPanel with random locations/sizes. On my actionListener, when I try to draw the circle, it gives me red lines on my drawOval

1st class:

```
 import java.awt.BorderLayout;
 import java.awt.Color;
 import java.awt.Dimension;
 import java.awt.FlowLayout;
 import java.awt.Graphics;
 import java.awt.GridLayout;
 import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
 import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
 import java.util.Random;
 import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
 import javax.swing.JButton;
 import javax.swing.JPanel;
 import javax.swing.JTextArea;

/**
 * 
 * @author Chris
 *
 */
 public class CirclesPanel extends JPanel{
 private JButton draw, clear;
 private JTextArea textArea;
 private JPanel panel, drawPanel, buttonPanel;
 private int count;

 /**constructor
* builds the frame
*/
 public CirclesPanel(){

//creates buttons and textArea
  draw = new JButton("Draw"); 
  clear = new JButton("Clear");
  textArea = new JTextArea(1,10);
  textArea.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Circles"));

//creats panel
 JPanel panel = new JPanel();
 panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
 setPreferredSize(new Dimension(620, 425));
//creates subpanel drawPanel
 JPanel drawPanel = new JPanel();
 drawPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(450,400));
 drawPanel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
//creates subpanel buttonPanel
 JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
 buttonPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,1));
//adds all the content to the frame
 add(panel);
 add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
 add(drawPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);
 buttonPanel.add(textArea);
 buttonPanel.add(draw);
 buttonPanel.add(clear);
//reads if the draw button is clicked
 draw.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
      count =Integer.parseInt(textArea.getText());//takes the count in
      repaint();//repaints the picture to add the circles
    }
 }); 
//reads if the clear button is clicked
 clear.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
            count=0;//sets the count to 0 so nothing is painted
              repaint();//repaints the window
            }
         }); 



 }
/**Paint component
 * draws the random circles
 */
  public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
 Random generator = new Random();
 int x, y, diameter;
 for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){ //loop that takes the count and does this "x" times
  g.setColor(Color.BLUE);//sets color to blue
  x = generator.nextInt(90);//random location for x
  y = generator.nextInt(90);//random location for y
  diameter = generator.nextInt(30);//random size
  g.fillOval(x, y, diameter, diameter);//draws the circle
    }
}
 }
```

2nd class

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;


public class Circles { 
public static void main(String[]args){
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Cicles HW9");
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

frame.getContentPane().add(new CirclesPanel());

frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);


}
}
```

Comment: I think by `red lines` you mean that the IDE shows error in calling the undefined `drawOval` method.

Comment: Your code doesn't compile. (at method drawOval)

Comment: All custom painting should be performed in the paintComponent method. Check out [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) and [2D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/) for more details

Comment: Ive painted graphics in the past a few times but I dont know how I would add it to the action listener

Comment: Take a look at this http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/

Answer (score 1):

So in your, I did little addition, first of all, I made the whole program in one class(CIRLCES PANEL), IF You want to use the second class, you can use it.... 
Problem is coming, your program is not the reading the **ActionPerformed** method for the drawing, means it is not located with the button, now I directly added it with your **button(DRAW),** now whenever you click on the button, it automatically reads the your **textArea** value, and draw your circles. I made your text area FINAL, So you can use it anywhere......

Now things that you need to do----
- this program is drawing circle on the whole frame, means not on your drawing Panel, you need to set the values, so it will draw on your draw panel area
- Also you need to add color for your oval, because it will either draw black color circle, which you will not able to see.....

and also one thing I forget to mentioned you, is that your, you also need to add code for your clear method...

```
 import java.awt.BorderLayout;
 import java.awt.Color;
 import java.awt.Dimension;
 import java.awt.FlowLayout;
 import java.awt.Graphics;
 import java.awt.GridLayout;
 import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
 import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
 import java.util.Random;
 import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
 import javax.swing.JButton;
 import javax.swing.JPanel;
 import javax.swing.JTextArea;


 public class CirclesPanel extends JPanel{
 private JButton draw, clear;
 private JTextArea textArea;
 private JPanel panel, drawPanel, buttonPanel;
 private int count;

 public CirclesPanel(){

JButton draw = new JButton("Draw");
JButton clear = new JButton("Clear");
final JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(1,10);
textArea.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Circles"));


JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
setPreferredSize(new Dimension(620, 425));

JPanel drawPanel = new JPanel();
drawPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(450,400));
drawPanel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
buttonPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,1));

add(panel);
add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
add(drawPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);
buttonPanel.add(textArea);
buttonPanel.add(draw);
buttonPanel.add(clear);

draw.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
          count =Integer.parseInt(textArea.getText());
          repaint();
    }
});        
}

  public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
  Random generator = new Random();
  int x, y, diameter;
  for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
     x = generator.nextInt(90);
    y = generator.nextInt(90);
    diameter = generator.nextInt(30);
    g.drawOval(x, y, diameter, diameter);


 }
 }


 }
```

[image]

Comment: yeah one more thing, if there is any step that is unclear to you, fell free to ask me...

Comment: Don't ever forget to call `super.paintComponent` or expect random crap to painted to your component

Comment: What do you mean madProgrammer?

Comment: @CRazyProgrammer I tried your code and it doesnt paint anything

Comment: I try to add buttons like how you have yours set up to the code that Drogba put but the layout is messed up

Comment: oo I c, now what's the problem is, its not drawing over the JPanel, let me fix it...

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is **drawing some random circles** on the `drawPanel` when **button clicked**. I write you a **simplified version** to show how things work.

[image: sample]

I only keep the `drawButton` and `paintPanel` to keep things simple.

```
public class PaintFrame extends JFrame {

    private JPanel content = new JPanel();
    private JButton drawButton = new JButton("Draw");
    private PaintPanel paintPanel = new PaintPanel();

    public PaintFrame() {

        getContentPane().add(content);
        content.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        drawButton.setSize(100, 500);
        drawButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // drawButton is fired, repaint the paintPanel
                paintPanel.repaint();
            }
        });
        content.add(drawButton, BorderLayout.WEST);
        content.add(paintPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

}
```

You need a new class extending the JPanel and override the `paintComponent` method to do the paint job for you. This **makes sure you are drawing on the panel**.

```
class PaintPanel extends JPanel {

    public PaintPanel() {
        setSize(500, 500);
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Random random = new Random();
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        // draw 5 random circles
        int count = 5;
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            g.drawOval(random.nextInt(250), random.nextInt(250),
                    random.nextInt(250), random.nextInt(250));
        }
    }

}
```

Main class

```
public class DrawMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame frame = new PaintFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(PaintFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(600, 500);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

Comment: Im trying to use your example to add my other buttons so it has "Draw" "clear" and an textArea for the ammount of circles. When I add buttons, it makes them all the same size and doesnt format how I want

Comment: `drawOval` parameters controls the size of the circle.

Comment: i updated it. It creates the circles in the top left corner instead of my drawPanel

Comment: @Chris You need a new class `PaintPanel`(or whatever name you called) extending `JPanel` and override the `paintComponent` method. This panel is **only** use for drawing purpose.