# Java JPanels graphics

Tags: java, swing, geometry, java-2d, paintcomponent

If I have many JPanels, how would I chose to draw on just one of them? I am trying to draw on my drawingPanel for random circles but that isnt working? I am having trouble getting my code to read my number from the textArea and generate that number of circles at random locations and random sizes in my panel to the right.

main

```
public class Circles {
public static void main(String[]args){
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Cicles HW9 Chris Houston");
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

frame.getContentPane().add(new CirclesPanel());

frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);


}
}
```

Panel

```
public class CirclesPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener{
private JButton draw, clear;
private JTextArea textArea;
private JPanel panel, drawPanel, buttonPanel;
private int count;

public CirclesPanel(){

    JButton draw = new JButton("Draw");
    JButton clear = new JButton("Clear");
    JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(1,10);
    textArea.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Circles"));


    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(620, 425));

    JPanel drawPanel = new JPanel();
    drawPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(450,400));
    drawPanel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

    JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
    buttonPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,1));

    add(panel);
    add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
    add(drawPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);
    buttonPanel.add(textArea);
    buttonPanel.add(draw);
    buttonPanel.add(clear);

    draw.addActionListener(this);
    clear.addActionListener(this);

}



public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    if(e.getSource() == draw){
        String tempText = textArea.getText();
        count = Integer.valueOf(tempText);
        repaint();


        }
    }

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    Random generator = new Random();
    int x, y, diameter;
    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++){
        x = generator.nextInt(90);
        y = generator.nextInt(90);
        diameter = generator.nextInt(30);
        g.drawOval(x, y, diameter, diameter);


}
  }
}
```

Comment: why open a new post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16205239/random-circles-java

Comment: I didnt know how to edit it to change my code to my updated one. Im sorry.